Creating Job Scheduler Dynamically from API and Endpoints
I'm looking for an explanation or demo of how to use Quartz.Net outside of initial program setup, as no where is this explained.
Here's a rundown of what I'm expecting the functionality to be and why I'm asking this question.  Let's say I have a database called ScheduledTasks.  Each row in ScheduledTasks is a separate job instance I plan on creating.  There's three rows in ScheduledTasks.  I start my application.  I would want those three rows to spawn off as Jobs (with schedules that are defined within ScheduledTask record).  Now, a user hits my API.  They send in new information about a new instance of the job (also a new record in ScheduledTasks) to create.  I would expect my application to consume this from the API, create the database record, and then spawn off a new Job with the definition from ScheduledTask, schedule it, and add it to the scheduler.  My issue so far is that nothing ANYWHERE explains how to do that outside of initial setup.
Is there a good direction to go with this?  Or is Quartz now all about setting up jobs only in the Program.cs?  That would seem kind of short sighted, but I can't find good examples of what I'm trying to explain.

"this is completely NOT how I plan on implementing it" - But it possibly should be, depending on the project type. What kind of project is it?

Using a database, I want to pick up a list of scheduled jobs that need to happen and then start them up at app start.  However, the bulk of it will be setting up new jobs via API calls to create them, as well as modifying ones that are already set up, stopping various jobs if they need to be stopped, and deleting jobs when we don't need them anymore.  Obviously, I can't do all of that in just the Program.cs file.

In Quartz, a job is (roughly) an object defined by an implementation of IJob (a job class) and possibly some job data. Usually, there’s one job per job class, but you could set up multiple jobs with that use the same job class and have different job data to create different variations (if you're familiar with partial function application, it would be similar to that). And, usually, jobs are created/configured at startup because you already know all the job classes that your system has. You could dynamically create jobs with existing job classes and new job data.

Are you planning to dynamically load assemblies to add new job classes? I'm wondering if you're using "job" to refer to what Quartz calls a "trigger" or even an execution of a job.

Maybe I didn't explain it well in my question.  I'll amend it and hope it makes sense.

You're using "job" to refer to triggers, and sometimes the conflation of jobs and triggers. You can't really expect to use Quartz until you're familiar with its concepts and frame your task in terms matching those concepts.

Without seeing what the table structure actually represents, I can only assume that you want the API to be able to create schedules. A controller can have ISchedulerFactory injected, and then its actions can use that to get IScheduler to manage the triggers.

Job: A particular set of instructions (usually a class and an Execute method) that is fired and run according to a Trigger.
Trigger: A set of instructions on the interval and/or frequency of when a related Job is to fire.

Okay, so what do you intend for the API to do, given those definitions?

The API would have an endpoint either called "CreateTask", "PauseTask", "EditTask", or "DeleteTask".  In each, it would either take in the full definition of a Task (which would be what Job is expected to run and what Trigger conditions it would run under)...or it would take a TaskID that would be used to look up in the scheduler for a given JobKey.  Then, it would do those given tasks of either creating, editing, pausing, or removing the Job/Trigger combination from the scheduler.

Quartz can only execute an implementation of IJob. Can your "task" be implemented as such, or are you trying to execute arbitrary code? You've switched from "job" to "task" but it still dances around this central question.

Sorry, you actually already answered my question.  And I'm sorry for getting confusing.  What I needed was to know that I can inject ISchedulerFactory to access the scheduler and add new Jobs.  I didn't know you could do that and no other source was telling me I could.  It's not how I usually work with DI, so that's why I was confused.
